# Seeing Errors when trying to Archive my Xcode project (Firebase issue not reactnative)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Foe the last couple months, I have been working on a ios mobile application and it all works (when I simulate it on my phone etc.) but when I go to archive it (to publish it to the Appstore) I see that there are two following errors:
[The errors That I see in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKEQf.png)

However I have not seen these before. Looking online, all the forums are talking about a react native version of Firebase (which I dont have) [The following are the list of pods in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uurln.png)

I have tried to comment out the "use_frameworks!" in my Podfile but since I am using other pods that wont help, I have also used ", :modular_headers => true" for the firebase pods (since I am not sure which ones use objective C) but none of those issues made any difference, I still see the same two errors. [The following picture is that of my Podfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYmRN.png)

I am really behind on my release date and I cant figure this out. I tried to clean and build again, I deleted my Derived data and tried running it again, I also tried removing the Podfile.lock and reinstalled the repos but none of those helped. I also tried to change the schemes and built the firebaseCore one but that still didnt solve anything. I don't understand that is happening during the archive and why this is not compiling like it does for when I run the project on my phone.

Currently using Xcode 10

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issue when archiving the app, you might wanna do uncheck parrelize build in the Edit Scheme... From your picture/screenshot i can see that you have already the build in debug version for your own testing which should be fine.

Unchecking the parallize build will cause the correct hierarchy of dependencies to be build in order. Try it and let me know if it helps.

I encounter an error like this a while back.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried doing that but it still seems to fail with the same issue. The thing is that I am not having any issues with the build but the archive. Let me know if there is anything else I can try. When I unchecked parallelize, I cleaned my project and built it and then tried to archive.

Comment: Have you tried making sure the React target build is the 1st one in the hierachcy for build?